# Making a list of all existing words of length n, and Microsoft Word macros in python

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make some words game. For that, I wanted to make a dictionary - a list of all the legit words in the length of 9.

That was no problem with `[f"{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}" for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in product(abc, repeat=9)]`.

My problem is so make sure the words I created are **legit** - "tzwzdddaa" is for example is not a real word, therefore I should not add it to the list, but "fuzziness" is.

**My (not working) solution:**
I thought about using Microsoft Word to detect the "bad" words, and then delete them. So I printed the words to a Microsoft Word file (.docx), and then used the macro shown [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/remove-all-misspelled-words-in-my-word-document/b686c318-c1fc-4d90-9e56-e922bb556abd?tab=AllReplies#tabs) to delete the unneeded words.

Because Words files go slower when they have a lot of text, I had to split the words the program created to different .docx files, each has 1500~ words. But way too many files were created, and I cannot go on each file seperatly and run that macro.

I am now trying to figure how to run this macro by using Python.
This way, everytime I am creating a new file, I can use this macro to remove the "bad" words, and in the end merge all files to one file, which will contain my list.

Bottom line:
**How can I make such a list, or how can I use Microsoft Word macros in Python?**

Notes:

The language of the words in this list are not in English - I found a list in English for words, but could not find such a list in the desired language.

In the program which makes the 9 letters words, I did a tiny optimization by canceling words which contains 3 of the same letter in a row. So "aaaaaaaaa" will not be on the list, but "aabaabaab" will be. But then again - "aabaabaab" is not a real word, therefore I should delete it.

```
if any(f"{a}{a}{a}" in word for a in abc):
    continue
```

**Thank you very much.**

Comment: You are trying to reproduce and check if real for `26**9=5 429 503 678 976`, which will take 5TB of space to store all of them. And will take FOREVER to iterate through all

Comment: Please, I would be glad to find a better solution! What can I do?

Comment: Why not just use a list of legit words in the first place? [Here's the first thing on google for "9 letter word lists"](https://www.bestwordlist.com/9letterwords.htm)

Comment: As I said in the notes - the language of the words in this list are not in English

Comment: I feel like the question should be more about _where can I find the list of N letter words in some language_. As pointed out by the first comment, it would be unrealistic to look up **5 trillion words** by yourself.

Comment: @Chris I spent over two hours trying to find such a list... There are plenty of online dictinoaries, but none of them lists words by length.

Comment: @Chris That's why I want to make a small list of say, 1000 words, run that macro, and then go on to the next 1000, and so on. I don't mind if it takes days. It will finish in some point

Comment: @Matan Here's another search: https://www.ezglot.com/more-words.php, which supports about 90 languages, and can be searched by length.

Comment: _I don't mind if it takes days. It will finish in some point_: if it takes 1 second to look up 1,000 words. It will take approximately 172 years.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for this website - however it doesn't seems to work - I cannot get any word. For example - the word "אריתמטיקה" (which means "Arithmetic") starts with "א" (reading from right to left). But searching for _ in Hebrew for length 9 gives no results.

Comment: Yes, you are right about how long it would take... Thanks @Chris